# Android Camera "Error -1" wenn calling camera.takePicture

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

in my Activity, i want to take a picture with android.hardware.Camera.
The code (see below) works fine in my AVD, but it doesn't work on my Android phone - all I get is "Error -1".

**AVD**:
Target: Android 2.3.3
SD Card: 64 MB
WVGA800

**Phone**:
Samsung Galaxy S2 with Android 2.3.6

**Code**:

    `android.hardware.Camera camera = Camera.open();

    camera.takePicture(null, null, mPictureCallback);

    camera.stopPreview();

    camera.setPreviewCallback(null);

    camera.release();

    camera = null;`

**Manifest:**

    `uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"

    uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"`

I don't think that the PictureCallback matters - when I comment everything in the onPictureTaken method, the same error is returned.
Also, I have restarted my phone, tried setting a few Camera parameters etc. - but nothing helps.
I can't find this specific error code for the Camera either.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a correct assigned **SurfaceView** it will not work.

Even the **SurfaceView** must have a minimum size.

Comment: Do I also have to add a SurfaceView when I want to take a picture and only save it (without displaying something)?

Comment: Yes, and the code is very delicate. Does not excuse very much.

Answer (score 0):

Your code have a important missing part. You need to call `startPreview()`, before calling `takePicture()`. Other important thing is that the photo taken can delay a little and java Garbage Colletor can collect your camera variable, before you have the result. So release the camera variable on the Picture Callback method.You also dont need to explicity define the `setPreviewCallback(null)`, you can remove it from your code.
It is important to avoid the excution of `startPreview()` twice before the picture be taken. Disable the element on your interface and enable after (and inside) the Callback method.